# Why am I not getting the table name form the view to the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, variables, post, laravel-blade

I have a dropdown menu on a blade where I print all the table from the DB, then I want to store the value of the option chosen and pass it to another controller that print me the tables inside another view.blade but I don't know how to pass this value.

Dropdown menu on Blade1

```
<form action="{{ 'Edit_TController@create' }}" method="post" id="ioa">


                                    <SELECT  id= "chosen" type="text" class="form-control @error('tables') is-invalid @enderror" name='chosen' style="width: 300px">

                                        @foreach($tables  as $chosen)
                                            <option value="{{ $chosen }}" > {{ $chosen }}</option>
                                        @endforeach


                                    </SELECT>


                                @error('tables')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror

                                </form>
```

Controller of Blade1

```
public function index(){

    $tables = array_map('reset', DB::select('SHOW TABLES'));

    return  view('edit')->with('tables',$tables);


}
```

Controller of blade2 (the blade where I want to print the table)

```
 public function create(){

   
    // $var = variable from the view

    $print = DB::table($var)->select('*')->get();

    return view('edit_t')->with('print',$print);
}
```

This is the web.php

```
Route::get('edit', [App\Http\Controllers\EditController::class, 'index'])->name('edit');
Route::get('edit_t',[App\Http\Controllers\Edit_TController::class, 'create'])->name('edit_t');
Route::post('edit_t/{{$chosen}}',[App\Http\Controllers\Edit_TController::class, 'create'])->name('edit_t');
```

Comment: your first para is not that clear, would you like to edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: what part exactly?